# Redirect upcoming request on Google Cloud VM

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, port, iptables

I'm trying to redirect the request comming from port XXX on my GC VM to another peer in my VPN, I already opened the port on the GC console, allowed the port with UFW and redirected it with iptables:

```html
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport XXX -j DN
AT --to-destination XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But none of this seems to work, I've tried redirecting to google, neither works.
I've also tried it with ubuntu and debian.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?, thanks

Comment: Do you have IP forwarding enabled? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#canipforward

Comment: Did you enable IP forwarding when you created the instance? What type of VPN? Show the route tables for the VPC. Show the route tables for on-premises. Edit your question after you have researched your problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: Hi, I would like to confirm with you if you enabled port forwarding from both sides. Is it enabled on the interface network on GCP and under the OS?

Comment: Hi, I already solved it, the problem was as you say that port forwading was disabled, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey glad to hear you solved your issue, If you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm that you enabled port forwarding on both sides.

- Here shows how to enable [port forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#canipforward) on GCP
- To enable it under the OS please run the followed commands as root:

`# echo 1> / proc / sys / net / ipv4 / ip_forward`

In order the forwarding bit remains active we will have to modify the file /etc/sysctl.conf and we will uncomment the line

`# net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Uncomment the line and reload

`sudo sysctl -p`

Now you can run your commands

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport xx -j DNAT --to-destination XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:xxxx`